# reindexing array inside object after unsetting few keys in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

So here we have an array function `array_values` but it is working if performing on the same array. Over here i have an object and inside that objst i have set of arrays and with few condition i have to unset few of the keys and reindex the array.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [details] => stdClass Object
    (
        [first] => 159
        [events] => Array
        (
           [0] => stdClass Object
           (
               [id]=>1,
               [name]=>abc
           )
           [1] => stdClass Object
           (
               [id]=>2,
               [name]=>abc
           ) 
           [2] => stdClass Object
           (
               [id]=>3,
               [name]=>abc
           )
       )
   )
)
```

Now if i unset the 1 key and do `json_encode` and while printing it by doing `json_decode`, then it becomes

```
stdClass Object
(
    [details] => stdClass Object
    (
        [first] => 159
        [events] => stdClass Object
        (
           [0] => stdClass Object
           (
               [id]=>1,
               [name]=>abc
           )
           
           [2] => stdClass Object
           (
               [id]=>3,
               [name]=>abc
           )
       )
   )
)
```

The events node becomes object, I don't want to change it from array to object. My result has to be exactly the same with reindexing the key.

Comment: Store the result of `array_values` back into the object property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_values()` to reindex an array.

```
$object->events = array_values($object->events);
```

Comment: thanks. It did work for me.